# How can I require at least one checkbox to be selected for user to submit form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a [checkboxgroup component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-checkbox-group) that I want to do some input validation on. At least one checkbox needs to be selected before the user can submit the form.

```
        <legend>Choose field names</legend>
        <CheckboxGroup
          checkboxDepth={5}
          name="fieldNames"
          value={this.state.fieldNames}
          onChange={this.fieldNamesChanged}
          required
        >
          {fields &&
            fields.map(field => {
              return (
                <li>
                  <Checkbox value={field.name} />
                  {field.name}
                </li>
              );
            })}
```

With what [I currently have in my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8nyykk01m9) the form can be submitted without selecting any checkboxes. Can the `required` attribute be used to fix this issue or do I need to keep track of selected boxes outside of this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// include a value in your state defaults
this.state = {
  ...,
  submitDisabled: true
};

// update the value when a checkboxe's value changes
fieldNamesChanged = newFieldNames => {
    this.setState({
        ...,
        submitDisabled: !newFieldNames.length
    });
};

// use the state value to toggle the disabled property
<button
    ...
    disabled={this.state.submitDisabled}>
    Submit
</button>
```

[Here's a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/o5nk4v399z).

Comment: Ah, yeah, I was trying to check the `.length` of the `fieldNames` state value on the required attribute inside the checkboxgroup component originally. Cheers. I need to clean up this component and abstract away some of the logic, it's way too bloated and hard to keep track of state changes at some points.